# Android CookieManager and Redirects

Tags: android, android-webview, http-redirect, android-cookiemanager

I'm setting two cookies using setCookie method from android.webkit.CookieManager -
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html with the same value for two different URLs.

However, I know that when I load the first URL on the webview, it will send me a HTTP redirect to the second URL for which I've also setted the cookie.

My question is: will the cookie manager send the cookie for the second URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

As long as a cookie fulfills the requirements (domain, path, secure, httponly, not expired, etc.) then the WebView will send the cookie along with each request.  This includes when the WebView makes a request for a redirect URL, if there are cookies that fulfill the requirements for the redirected URL then the WebView will send those cookies along with the request. So, if you explicitly set a cookie for the redirect URL then it should be included when the WebView follows the redirect and makes a request for the redirect URL.

**Example 1**
Use `android.webkit.CookieManager` to set the cookies that *all* `WebView` instances will use. I typically do this in my Activity's `onCreate()` method, or my Fragment's `onViewCreated()` method, but you can configure the `CookieManager` in almost any lifecycle method, but it **must** be done before the `WebView` loads the url.  This is an example of configuring the `CookieManager` in `onViewCreated()`.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //Replace R.id.webview with whatever ID you assigned to the WebView in your layout
    WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview);  

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

    //originalUrl is the URL you expect to generate a redirect
    cookieManager.setCookie(originalUrl, "cookieKey=cookieValue");

    //redirectUrl is the URL you expect to be redirected to
    cookieManager.setCookie(redirectUrl, "cookieKey=cookieValue");

    //Now have webView load the originalUrl. The WebView will automatically follow the redirect to redirectUrl and the CookieManager will provide all cookies that qualify for redirectUrl.
    webView.loadUrl(originalUrl);

}
```

**Example 2**
If you know that the redirect URL will be in the same apex domain, ex. `mydomain.com` will redirect to `redirect.mydomain.com`, or `www.mydomain.com` will redirect to `subdomain.mydomain.com`, or `subdomain.mydomain.com` will redirect to `mydomain.com`, then **you can set one cookie for the entire *mydomain.com* domain**.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //Replace R.id.webview with whatever ID you assigned to the WebView in your layout
    WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview);  

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

    //Set the cookie for the entire domain - notice the use of a . ("dot") at the front of the domain
    cookieManager.setCookie(".mydomain.com", "cookieKey=cookieValue");

    //Now have webView load the original URL. The WebView will automatically follow the redirect to redirectUrl and the CookieManager will provide all cookies for the domain.
    webView.loadUrl(originalUrl);

}
```